# How should I join 2 table by first name and last name to get one result?

Tags: mysql

I have two separate tables and the only way to match the 2 exactly is by the columns `fname` and `lname`.  This is an attempt to get a phone extension from on table based on the `fname` and `lname` from the other table.

This is the "extensions" table (which have the phone extension numbers):

| id | fname | lname | location | position | extension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

This is the "directory" table (which has the location):

| id | ext | fname | lname | fullName | location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

I am wanting to query by `directory.location` and display the following:

| First name | Last name | Title | Location | Extension |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Answer (score 1):

Just join the two tables:

```sql
select u.fname, u.lname, u.title, d.extension
from users as u
join directory as d on u.fname = d.fname and u.lname = d.lname
where d.location = 'woswasi'
```

Comment: please forgive my ignorance but should I replace all the "d"s with directory and the "u"s with "exertions"?  I did see that users might have meant to be extensions. The "join" concept completely confuses me,  I will get it eventually.   Thank you!!

Comment: u and d are just aliases. You can also use the full tablenames. (I.e. extensions.lname)

Comment: This is what I needed .. Thank you!